# Condition for $f(x)$ to be increasing on $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+5\sin^2x$ is an increasing function on $\mathbb R$. I need to find the condition on $a$ and $b$.

I know $f'(x)\ge0$, which gives $f'(x) = 3x^2+2ax+b+5\sin 2x\ge0$. I don't know how to proceed further. I could find the condition for $3x^2+2ax+b>=−5$ but I feel like that would be a subset of the actual solution.

Comment: Your computation of $f'(x)$ is wrong.

Comment: Fixed, I wrote sinx instead of sin2x sorry

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: are you sure ?

Comment: @skyking: I don't think so, the previous expression was with $5\sin x$, which the OP fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to impose, as you say, that $f'(x)>0$ for every $x$. So,
$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax+b+10 \sin(x) \cos(x)>0.$$

Observe that $ -0. 5 \leq  \sin(x) \cos(x) \leq 0.5$. Hence, a **sufficient** condition is:

$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax+b+10 \sin(x) \cos(x) \geq 3x^2 + 2ax+b-5 =:p(x).$$

We want $p$ to be on the positive half line for every $x$. Since $p$ is a convex parabola, it has its minimum at the point $x^\ast$ such that $p'(x^\ast)=0$ which is $x^\ast=-a/3$. So we want $p(x^\ast) = p(-a/3)\geq 0$. This gives us the equation:

$$p(-a/3)= b-5-\frac{a^2}{3} \geq 0.$$

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I think the point of the OP's question was that he didn't want a sufficient condition, but a characterization.